Build .NET MAUI 9 app using GitHub Actions
I've been using the following YAML file in GitHub Actions to build my .NET MAUI app and upload it to TestFlight for quite some time without any issues.
I just updated it slightly to use .NET 9 as opposed to .NET 8 and now it's failing in the step that is supposed to download Apple Provisioning Profile with the following error:

Error: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported

I think it's related to XCode but haven't figured it out yet. Any idea what maybe causing this and how to fix it?
Here's the YAML file:
name: Build & Publish MyApp iOS

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  build-pack-n-ship:

    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
    - uses: maxim-lobanov/setup-xcode@v1
      with:
        xcode-version: latest
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 9.0.x
    - name: Install MAUI workload
      run: dotnet workload install maui
    - name: Import Code-Signing Certificates
      uses: Apple-Actions/import-codesign-certs@v1
      with:
        p12-filepath: 'MyAppleDistributionCert.p12'
        p12-password: ${{ secrets.CERTIFICATES_P12_PASSWORD }}
    - name: Download Apple Provisioning Profiles
      uses: Apple-Actions/download-provisioning-profiles@v1
      with:
        bundle-id: 'com.mycompany.myapp'
        issuer-id: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_ISSUER_ID }}
        api-key-id: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_KEY_ID }}
        api-private-key: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build and Publish
      run: dotnet publish -c Release -f:net9.0-ios /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true /p:EnableAssemblyILStripping=false
    - name: List generated files
      run: ls -l
    - name: Upload Build Artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3.0.0
      with:
        path: '**/*.ipa'
    - name: Archive dSYM files
      run: zip -r dSYMs.zip . -i ./MyApp/bin/Release/net9.0-ios/ios-arm64/*.app.dSYM
    - name: Upload dSYM Artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3.0.0
      with:
        name: dSYMs
        path: '**/dSYMs.zip'
    - name: 'Upload app to TestFlight'
      uses: apple-actions/upload-testflight-build@v1
      with: 
        app-path: './MyApp/bin/Release/net9.0-ios/ios-arm64/publish/MyApp.ipa'
        issuer-id: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_ISSUER_ID }}
        api-key-id: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_KEY_ID }}
        api-private-key: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY }}


I don't think this has anything to do with .NET MAUI or .NET 9 tbh. Searching for this error message will give me all kinds of results about credentials maybe be corrupted or not correctly formatted in the secrets. If you remove the provisioning profile and signing stuff, does it actually build correctly? I do see you set setup Xcode to latest, you probably want that to be 16.0 in order for the .NET MAUI app to build, but I doubt it will fix this.
